# write textbox data to text file

Tags: text, filestream

I have code that is supposed to take all the user data that was input after the program was run and put it all into a text file.

Here is the code so far:

```
protected void WriteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\4567\MyDocuments\ExporterOutput.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        TextBox[] tbs = { username, TextBox2, sgml, Path };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (TextBox tb in tbs)
            sb.AppendLine(tb.Text);
        sb.AppendLine(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString());

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:/Users/4567/My Documents/ExporterOutput.txt", sb.ToString());
```

I tried running it and the text file just shows up blank. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and if there is an easier way to output all textbox information to a text file. And preferrable in a certain format.

---

Here is the edited code from the suggestions you gave me:

```
 protected void WriteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox[] tbs = { username, TextBox2, sgml, Path };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (TextBox tb in tbs)
            sb.AppendLine(tb.Text);
        sb.AppendLine(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString());

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Users\\oZ012D\\My Documents\\ExporterOutput.txt", sb.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Which programming language is your code written in?

Comment: Looks like c#. I cant quite figure out why the Array of textboxes wouldn't print their text.  The DropDownLists are probably being used incorrectly

Comment: I am using asp.net c#, the code-behind.

Comment: @Akron how should the dropdownlists be used to output properly?

Comment: What object type are they?  I work with C# GUIs, but Im no expert.  If they actually are DropdownList (like the name you have implies) then using the .Text property would be my best bet.  I typically do guess and check for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Akron I created them in design mode. Should I just take out the ToString and replace with Text? I tried that and it is still giving me errors.

Comment: Does this compile?  Do you have any idea where the error is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Im going to take a few guesses here.

Your last line should be

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Users\\4567\\My Documents\\ExporterOutput.txt", sb.ToString());
```

You are using windows, so you need the "\" char and not the forward slash like you would on Linux.  This is accomplished by having the double backslash (which c# recognizes as a single backslash) in your string.

Also, try getting rid of your first line.  You are creating a file stream and then not using or closing it.  I think its possible that the open FS is causing issues.

Don't worry about creation issues, the WriteAllText() call will create the file if it doesn't exist and will overwrite it if it does.

Let me know if that works, the only other thing that looks potentially incorrect to me is the way you are getting text from the drop down menus.

Comment: Should the dropdownlists not use the appendline?

Comment: Appendline is fine.  Im just wondering what text exactly is generated by calling .SelectedItem.ToString().  If you run it and it works, check and see what is getting into the output file from these DropDownLists.  If it is what you want it to be, then good!

Comment: It isn't outputting anything from any of the textboxes. I have a browse button that creates a txt file and saves it and I wanted it in that file but none of the information is being output.

Comment: I'm assuming you made the changes I recommended. At this point, I really don't know.  I would have to go through it line by line to see where the data is going missing.

Comment: Here is the code with the changes-(kept the ToString because I was getting errors) { TextBox[] tbs = { username, TextBox2, sgml, Path }; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); foreach (TextBox tb in tbs) sb.AppendLine(tb.Text); sb.AppendLine(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString()); sb.AppendLine(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString()); System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Users\\oZ012D\\My Documents\\ExporterOutput.txt", sb.ToString()); }

Comment: Well, it looks correct to me.  I would try and go through it line by line and figure out why its not printing.  (For example, create a text box and try setting its text to sb.ToString() just before you output it to the file.  Repeat this at various points in the code to try and figure out where the expected text is going missing.)  I recommend using a textbox because it appears to be an easy way for you to see the data that is getting passed around.  I really don't know what else could be going wrong.